# Use slider controls to set function domain of plotted function

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I want to display `Plot[f,{t, t1, t2}]` in a `Manipulate` with the domain `{t1, t2}` specified by slider controls with something like

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[t^2, {t, t1, t2}],
  {{t1, -1, "t1"}, -2, 2, 0.1},
  {{t2, 1, "t2"}, -2, 2, 0.1}]
```

In particular, I want to require `t1 < t2` and to display a warning if `t1 =  t2` or `t1 > t2`. Although the above code produces an error when `t1 = t2`, *Mathematica* appears to switch the roles of `t1` and `t2` when the sliders are set to `t1 > t2`.

I have tried the control statements

```
{{t1, -1, "t1"}, -2, 2, 0.1},
{{t2, 1, "t2"}, t1, 2, 0.1}
```

but to no avail.

An alternative solution is just to eliminate the sliders and instead provide input fields for `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: Have you considered `If[t1 < t2, Plot[...], warning]`?  Put it inside a `Pane` to control `ImageSize` if desired.

Comment: I replaced the Plot statement with
Pane[If[ t1 < t2, Plot[t^2, {t, t1, t2}], Style["Require t2 > t1"]].
That works nicely.

Comment: You could put your comment into an answer. :)  Also, if you have V10, then there's `[`IntervalSlider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html)`, which might help you avoid the issue entirely, if that would be preferable.

Comment: @Michael E2: IntervalSlider - a great solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to handle your problem.

Simple -- give a warning of slider interference:

```
Manipulate[
  If[t1 < t2, Plot[t^2, {t, t1, t2}], "Warning: t1 > t2"],
  {{t1, -1}, -2, 2, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{t2, 1}, -2, 2, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

More elegant user interface, less elegant code -- prevent slider interference:

I have to give up `Manipulate`'s simple control specification format for the sliders because I want to use the second argument of `Dynamic` to constrain the slider thumbs.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[t^2, {t, t1, t2}],
  Row[{
    "t1 ", 
    Slider[Dynamic[t1, (t1 = If[# >= t2, t1, #]) &], {-2, 2, 0.1}, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"]}],
  Row[{
    "t2 ", 
    Slider[Dynamic[t2, (t2 = If[# <= t1, t2, #]) &], {-2, 2, 0.1}, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"]}],
  {{t1, -1}, None},
  {{t2, 1}, None}]
```

I prefer the second method because I believe it is better to prevent bad things from happening than to give warnings that they have happened.